# How to define arbitrary attributes on a mocked class's objects?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a class defined in a module `abc.myModule`:

```
Class MyClass:
  def __init__(self, a):
     self.a_value = a
```

Now I have script that does:

```
c = MyClass('a')
print c.a_value
```

Now in my unit test for the above, I want to patch `MyClass` so any object of `MyClass` will return '`XYZ`' for its  `a._value()`.  So I do:

```
@patch('abc.myModule.MyClass, a_value=True)
```

This patch will cause `MyClass` to have `.a_value()` return True, but any object of `MyClass` still does not have a_value defined. What can I do to correct this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects of `MyClass` are created when `MyClass` is called. Therefore you just need to ensure that you set `a_value` on the return value of `MyClass`:

```
@patch('abc.myModule.MyClass', a_value=True) 
def test_something(self, mock_myclass):
    mock_myclass.return_value.a_value = True  # Ensure a_value is set for objects
```